# Automatic White Balancing with Grayworld assumption

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I have been trying to implement the white balancing algorithms provided by:
https://pippin.gimp.org/image-processing/chapter-automaticadjustments.html

I have used python and opencv to implement them. I am unable to produce the same results as in the website.

In grayworld assumption, for example, i use the following code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def show(final):
    print 'display'
    cv.imshow("Temple", final)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

def saveimg(final):
    print 'saving'
    cv.imwrite("result.jpg", final)

# Insert any filename with path
img = cv.imread("grayworld_assumption_0.png")
res = img
final = cv.cvtColor(res, cv.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

avg_a = -np.average(final[:,:,1])
avg_b = -np.average(final[:,:,2])

for x in range(final.shape[0]):
    for y in range(final.shape[1]):
        l,a,b = final[x][y]
        shift_a = avg_a * (l/100.0) * 1.1
        shift_b = avg_b * (l/100.0) * 1.1
        final[x][y][1] = a + shift_a
        final[x][y][2] = b + shift_b

final = cv.cvtColor(final, cv.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
final = np.hstack((res, final))
show(final)
saveimg(final)
```

I am getting the result

[image]

instead of 
[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does `cv.imread()` defaults to BGR? I had assumed it uses RGB, but I cannot find the docs right now. Could that be the issue? ...NVM found the docs, and uses BGR by default.

Comment: @norok It says here in http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html, "In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in B G R order."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The document you are implementing is not aware of CV internal conventions for [LAB definition](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) in case of 8-bit color depth.

In particular:

```
L: L / 100 * 255
A: A + 128
B: B + 128
```

I believe this is done for improved accuracy, because then one could use `unsigned int8` precision in full for the luminosity while keeping a consistent unsigned data type for the whole array.

The code below, adapted from yours should work.
Note that there are some minor fixes here and there (*EDIT* including wrapping up the interesting code in a function), but the actual *sauce* is within the nested `for` loop.

```
from __future__ import (
    division, absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals)

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


def show(final):
    print('display')
    cv.imshow('Temple', final)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

# Insert any filename with path
img = cv.imread('grayworld_assumption_0.png')

def white_balance_loops(img):
    result = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    avg_a = np.average(result[:, :, 1])
    avg_b = np.average(result[:, :, 2])
    for x in range(result.shape[0]):
        for y in range(result.shape[1]):
            l, a, b = result[x, y, :]
            # fix for CV correction
            l *= 100 / 255.0
            result[x, y, 1] = a - ((avg_a - 128) * (l / 100.0) * 1.1)
            result[x, y, 2] = b - ((avg_b - 128) * (l / 100.0) * 1.1)
    result = cv.cvtColor(result, cv.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    return result

final = np.hstack((img, white_balance_loops(img)))
show(final)
cv.imwrite('result.jpg', final)
```

### EDIT:

The same result, but with much faster performances can be obtained by avoiding loops:

```
def white_balance(img):
    result = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    avg_a = np.average(result[:, :, 1])
    avg_b = np.average(result[:, :, 2])
    result[:, :, 1] = result[:, :, 1] - ((avg_a - 128) * (result[:, :, 0] / 255.0) * 1.1)
    result[:, :, 2] = result[:, :, 2] - ((avg_b - 128) * (result[:, :, 0] / 255.0) * 1.1)
    result = cv.cvtColor(result, cv.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    return result
```

which obviously gives the same result:

```
print(np.all(white_balance(img) == white_balance_loops(img)))
True
```

but with very different timings:

```
%timeit white_balance(img)
100 loops, best of 3: 2 ms per loop

%timeit white_balance_loops(img)
1 loop, best of 3: 529 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you help with writing these codes also in C++?

Comment: It's probably simpler to just ask your own question for C++... if you want you can reference this question, though. The code would be similar to the non vectorized one.