# White balance and colour converting

Tags: python, image-processing

I am a coding beginner and I have found a code for adjusting the white balance in images. The code works and colours are changing.
Actually, all images which I took have a problem with the white balance and I wanted to adjust this with a simple code. The code I have used seemed to work the best (I tried different codes I found on the internet).
The problem is that river areas become coloured red after the transformation. I don't know if this is happening because of the white balance or because my colour transformation is wrong.
Can someone please help me.

This is the code I have used

```
import cv2 as cv
# import numpy as np

#
img = cv.imread("C:\\Users\\die5k\\Desktop\\NeuerOrdner\\DJI_0207.jpg")
r, g, b = cv.split(img)
r_avg = cv.mean(r)[0]
g_avg = cv.mean(g)[0]
b_avg = cv.mean(b)[0]

 # Find the gain of each channel
k = (r_avg + g_avg + b_avg) / 3
kr = k / r_avg
kg = k / g_avg
kb = k / b_avg

r = cv.addWeighted(src1=r, alpha=kr, src2=0, beta=0, gamma=0)
g = cv.addWeighted(src1=g, alpha=kg, src2=0, beta=0, gamma=0)
b = cv.addWeighted(src1=b, alpha=kb, src2=0, beta=0, gamma=0)

balance_img = cv.merge([b, g, r])
balance_img = cv.cvtColor(balance_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv.imwrite('result0207.jpg', balance_img)
```

This is my input image
[image]
This is my outcome
[image]

Comment: Skewed by the amount of green foliage?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Do you have a link(s) to any better/preferred white balance algorithm(s) please?

Comment: @Mark: The only fail-safe method is to measure the illumination, of course. There are many methods to estimate the illumination from the image content, but none that will not give bad results for certain classes of inputs. [This is a very simple method that works reasonably well](https://web.stanford.edu/~sujason/ColorBalancing/simplestcb.html) ([publication](https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/llmps-scb/article.pdf)) -- everything else is significantly more complex.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I found this page,too but I don´t understand how this is working. Can you explain it perhaps? Thank you for your comments and help.

Comment: @user2864740 the problem is that half of my images look normal and half like the super green one I have posted. The problem is I use orthomosaics and the alignment is really bad with the 'two kind' of images I have.

Comment: @Tapsi: what that method does is stretch the histogram of each channel independently. It assumes that in each channel you want to have both zero exposure pixels and maximum exposure pixels. If there is any white in the picture, this is obviously true, but also if there is no white, this often still holds. But of course for some cases this is not true. If your picture only has trees, there’s only green in it, and any form of auto white balance will make the green white or gray.

Answer (score 1):

**OpenCV** uses BGR ordering. Change this:

```
r, g, b = cv.split(img)
```

to this:

```
b, g, r = cv.split(img)
```

And remove this:

```
balance_img = cv.cvtColor(balance_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

because **OpenCV** knows to convert to RGB when saving files.

Comment: But that wouldn’t fix the issue, would it?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hi Cris, I wasn't at a computer in order to check when I answered. I just saw that no-one had answered in 4 hours and decided to point out a couple of issues I could see that might hopefully help OP move forwards. I'll have a check later on when I can test.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried your suggestion but it still lead to the same image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Having now got to a computer, I agree that the method still fails for this image. I also tried converting to floats and applying the correction and clipping the results to range but that doesn't help. I think the method itself fails for this subject matter. I also tried the correction suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391574/2836621 and whilst better, the result is still incorrect.

Comment: I think that OP's method and the one you link try to set the average color to gray? I don't see how that is useful in general, but it certainly doesn't hold for OP's picture that is mostly green. Automatic white balance is hard!!! :)