# How To Brighten A OpenCV Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, style-transfer

I have managed to get a saliency map of an image using the following code below. Here it obtains the saliency map as well as the inverse saliency map and then applies the results to the image in order to get the foreground and background of the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def SalienceMaps(image_path):
    
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    
    dimensions = (350, 450)    
    resized = cv2.resize(image, dimensions, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
    saliency = cv2.saliency.StaticSaliencyFineGrained_create()
    (success, saliencyMap) = saliency.computeSaliency(resized)
    
    (B, G, R) = cv2.split(resized)
    
    salBlue = B * saliencyMap.astype(saliencyMap.dtype)
    salGreen = G * saliencyMap.astype(saliencyMap.dtype)
    salRed= R * saliencyMap.astype(saliencyMap.dtype)
    
    salBlue = salBlue.astype("uint8")
    salGreen = salGreen.astype("uint8")
    salRed = salRed.astype("uint8")
    
    reduction = np.ones((450,350))
    inverse = reduction - saliencyMap
    
    inverseBlue = B * inverse.astype(inverse.dtype)
    inverseGreen = G * inverse.astype(inverse.dtype)
    inverseRed = R * inverse.astype(inverse.dtype)
    
    inverseBlue = inverseBlue.astype("uint8")
    inverseGreen = inverseGreen.astype("uint8")
    inverseRed = inverseRed.astype("uint8")
    
    main = cv2.merge((salBlue, salGreen, salRed))
    inverse = cv2.merge((inverseBlue, inverseGreen, inverseRed))

    return (main, inverse)

(main, inverse) = SalienceMaps("Content Image.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Image", main)
cv2.imshow("Image 2", inverse)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I get the following output for the foreground and background respectively when this image has been put in:

[image] [image][image]

I was wondering, how to improve the brightness or features of the foreground so the features are a lot more prominant and the image is brighter if that makes sense? Any idea what could be done? Cheers

Comment: Not sure if it would improve your foreground features (while not also changing the background), but you could try applying some white balance to improve contrast in general (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390779/automatic-white-balancing-with-grayworld-assumption/46391574).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cv2.normalize() in Python/OpenCV to increase brightness.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read images
img = cv2.imread('img.png')

# stretch mask to full dynamic range
result = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=350, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

# write results
cv2.imwrite("img_enhanced.png", result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: One thing i want to check, if I normalize both, will the output still be the original image?

Comment: What do you mean by normalize both?  Do you mean your two input images? If so, then the output might be too bright since you are normalizing twice. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant normalize the foreground and background pictures that are obtained? I  think the background pictures for these images in this case are fine but it's the foreground that is a lot darker. However, I might normalize the starting image and then break them out and see if I get any different results. Would this be a good method?

Comment: I am still unsure what you want. But it is easy enough to test which images need to be normalized and look at the results from doing that.

Comment: Yeah that's my plan! Thank you very much for your contribution, it's definitely going to help!