# Updating the l,a,b values of the Mat Vector

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I tried to implement the solution below to **C++** and use it as a reference for my own problem.

[Automatic White Balancing with Grayworld assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390779/automatic-white-balancing-with-grayworld-assumption/46391574?noredirect=1#comment123207736_46391574)

Here is my progress:

```
cap>>frame;

cvtColor(frame, res, COLOR_BGR2Lab);
Point3_<uchar> pixelData;

int step = frame.step;
int channels = res. channels();
for( int i = 0; i< res.rows; i++){
    for(int j= 0 ; j<res.cols; j++){
        //*L
        pixelData.x = res.data[step*i + channels*j + 0];
        pixelData.x *= 100/255.0;
        //*a
        pixelData.y = res.data[step*i + channels*j + 1];
        pixelData.y *= (frame.data[step*i + channels*j + 1] ) - ((pixelData.y - 128) * (pixelData.x/100) * 1.1);
        //*b
        pixelData.z = res.data[step*i + channels*j + 2];
        pixelData.z *= (frame.data[step*i + channels*j + 2] ) - ((pixelData.z - 128) * (pixelData.x/100) * 1.1);
    }
res.at<Mat>(1) = pixelData.y; //HOW TO DO THIS PART???
res.at<Mat>(2) = pixelData.z;
}
cvtColor(res, res, COLOR_Lab2BGR);
```

**I have 2 questions**

1. I guess, the approach is to arranging the l,a,b parameters to a proper scale and then updating the LAB Mat vector.
   I am stuck with updating the L A B parameters in **res**
2. How to convert the `final = np.hstack((img, white_balance_loops(img)))` part in the reference link to C++?

Answer (score 0):

1. 

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve there...

You store results into `pixelData` at each j-loop but you don't do anything with it, and overwrite it in your next loop.

```
res.at<Mat>(1) = pixelData.y; //HOW TO DO THIS PART???
res.at<Mat>(2) = pixelData.z;
```

And what is this about?

2.
You can use [cv::hconcat](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf9771c991763233866bf76b5b5d1776f) and [cv::vconcat](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga744f53b69f6e4f12156cdde4e76aed27) to concatenate OpenCV matrices.