# Adjust image white balance by setting new gray point using OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, photoshop

In Photoshop there is an option to adjust the white balance of an image by choosing a new gray point. When that is done each image pixel color is recalculated based on that single gray pixel color. I am trying to automate this process in python. You can check this short [video explaining the process in photoshop.](https://youtu.be/MUh3vZT0tbo?t=55)

[image: Photoshop UI for adjusting gray point of an image]

**Question 1. What is the function that is used to transform pixels when you have a new gray point color (RGB) values.**

Note 1. I could not find any information on how this is actually calculated.
Note 2. I already found the pixel that I want to use as a new gray point.

**Question 2. What is the python code to apply this function to an image using OpenCV.**

Comment: Search Google for "grayworld whitebalancing". For example, https://web.stanford.edu/~sujason/ColorBalancing/grayworld.html or https://pippin.gimp.org/image-processing/chapter-automaticadjustments.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390779/automatic-white-balancing-with-grayworld-assumption

Comment: Q1: likely it's calculating a gamma adjustment from that "gray point". -- for proper white-balance, one would have to transform from gamma-compressed to linear, then *scale* the color channels, then gamma-compress again. -- just messing with the gamma won't color-correct a picture properly. you'll see different hues showing up in darks, mids, and brights.

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for your comment, I did try the grayworld method, however it uses avg lab, what I am looking for is using my own gray point RGB values to adjust the image.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz do you have a reference to an algorithm that does all these conversions?

Comment: Pick some color that you think is "gray" or as close to gray as you want. Then see the formulae at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance. In place of 255 use 255/2 as the true gray (or whatever value you want for gray). Then process each pixel with that formula.